Spring Login Session
I have a problem with my login process. When successfully logged in, the user cannot see/visit any non-public pages (just returns the user to the login form) and the problem has to be in Spring Authentication - thats snippet of code in the controller on successfuly login:
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password); Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken); SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
and SecurityConfig.java:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/logged", "/login", "/register").permitAll() // Allow public access
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // All other requests require authentication
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") // Specify your login page
                .permitAll() // Allow everyone to see the login page
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = 
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
@Bean
    public CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

I tried some google researches but couldnt resolve the problem

Why do you have a controller for login? The formLogin already handles the login feature of Spring Security, why are you working around that?
